# How to change the import statement based on variable in ( Style.scss ) file

Tags: javascript, css, angular, webpack, sass

I have this import statement in my project

```
@import "./assets/sass/style.angular.scss";
```

How i can change the path based on a variable. I want to make it change when user change the language of the project to arabic use this path

```
@import "./assets/sass/style.angular.RTL.css";
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a built-in functionality of angular, but you could always add a class to your app.component file based on the language, or a data tag. Something like this:

```js
@Component({
    templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
    selector: 'app-component
})
export class AppComponent {
    @HostBinding('attr.data-lang') language: string = "en";
}
```

then in your style.angular.RTL.css file you would prefix your selectors with [data-lang="arabic" to have it kick in whenever the language variable was set to arabic.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in need of if-else inside the `.scss` file, you can check this approach

```
// Define a mixin to import what file needs to be imported

@mixin importRightScssFile($firstUrl: true) {

  @if $firstUrl {
    @import('path/to/your/first-url.scss');
  } @lse {
    @import('path/to/your/second-url.scss');
  }
}

// Whenever you want you can simply use this **mixin** to load whatever URL you want like this: 

.first-url-class {
 @include importRightScssFile($firstUrl: true);
}

.second-url-class {
 @include importRightScssFile($firstUrl: false);
}
```